# Embed ruby into javascript string

Tags: javascript, ruby, embedded-ruby

I want to embed `tfx-<%= @doc.doc[:b].metadata['filename']} %>` into a javascript string called 'url'

```
url = "<%= @document.doc[:a].url(response_content_disposition: ContentDisposition.attachment( [INSERT HERE] )) %>";
```

I want something like this:

```
  url = "<%= @document.doc[:a].url(response_content_disposition: ContentDisposition.attachment( tfx-#{ @doc.doc[:b].metadata['filename']} )) %>";
```

Comment: Would you share the entire file with it's name?

Comment: what is your desired result? (From the perspective of the javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an instance variable in the server:

```
@some_name = "tfx-#{@doc.doc[:b].metadata['filename']}"
```

And in my javascript file I used the variable:

```
url = "<%= @document.doc[:a].url(response_content_disposition: ContentDisposition.attachment(@some_name)) %>";
```